# creating new variable and applying conditional value based on a date range with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

New to Python and coding in general here so this should be pretty basic for most of you.

I basically created this dataframe with a Datetime index.

Here's the dataframe

```
df = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2019-12-31', freq='D')
```

I would now like to add a new variable to my df called "vacation" with a value of 1 if the date is between 2018-06-24 and 2018-08-24 and value of 0 if it's not between those dates. How can I go about doing this?
I've created a variable with a range of vacation but I'm not sure how to put these two together along with creating a new column for "vacation" in my dataframe.

```
vacation = pd.date_range(start = '2018-06-24', end='2018-08-24')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2019-12-31', freq='D')` will not create a `DataFrame` instead it will create a `DatetimeIndex`. You can then convert it into a `DataFrame` by having it as an index or a separate column.

```
# Having it as an index

datetime_index = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2019-12-31', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({}, index=datetime_index)
# Using numpy.where() to create the Vacation column
df['Vacation'] = np.where((df.index >= '2018-06-24') & (df.index <= '2018-08-24'), 1, 0)
```

[image]

Or

```
# Having it as a column

datetime_index = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2019-12-31', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': datetime_index})
# Using numpy.where() to create the Vacation column
df['Vacation'] = np.where((df['Date'] >= '2018-06-24') & (df['Date'] <= '2018-08-24'), 1, 0)
```

[image]

**Note:** Displaying only the first five rows of the dataframe `df`.

Comment: Thank you. I like your solution. Now just to get it to work in one additional way. Suppose I have variables vacation2018 and vacation2019. A set of dates in both years. I've created variables 
'vacation2018 = pd.date_range(start = '2018-06-27', end = '2018-09-01')
vacation2019 = pd.date_range(start = '2019-06-27', end='2019-08-31')'
What can I do to make my vacation variable 1 if datetime index falls in either of those dates?
I've tried: 
'df['vacation'] = np.where((df.index=vacation2018))'
but that's giving me syntax error.

Comment: You need not create separate date indexes such as 'vacation2018' and 'vacation2019', instead, you can just modify the condition as follows.

vacation_2018 =  (df.index >= '2018-06-27') & (df.index <= '2018-09-01')

vacation_2019 =  (df.index >= '2019-06-27') & (df.index <= '2019-08-31')

df['Vacation'] = np.where(vacation_2018 | vacation_2019, 1, 0)
If you find the answer satisfying please upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for new `DataFrame`:

```
i = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-08-26', freq='D')

m = (i > '2018-06-24') & (i < '2018-08-24') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'vacation': m.astype(int)}, index=i)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vacation':np.where(m, 1, 0)}, index=i)
```

---

```
print (df)
            vacation
2018-01-01         0
2018-01-02         0
2018-01-03         0
2018-01-04         0
2018-01-05         0
             ...
2018-08-22         1
2018-08-23         1
2018-08-24         0
2018-08-25         0
2018-08-26         0

[238 rows x 1 columns]
```

Solution for add new column to existing `DataFrame`:

Create mask by compare `DatetimeIndex` with chaining by `&` for `bitwise AND` and convert it to integer (`True` to `1` and `False` to `0`) or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
i = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-08-26', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 1}, index=i)

m = (df.index > '2018-06-24') & (df.index < '2018-08-24') 

df['vacation'] = m.astype(int)
#alternative
#df['vacation'] = np.where(m, 1, 0)
print (df)
            a  vacation
2018-01-01  1         0
2018-01-02  1         0
2018-01-03  1         0
2018-01-04  1         0
2018-01-05  1         0
       ..       ...
2018-08-22  1         1
2018-08-23  1         1
2018-08-24  1         0
2018-08-25  1         0
2018-08-26  1         0

[238 rows x 2 columns]
```

Another solution with `DatetimeIndex` and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - difference is `1` included `2018-06-24` and `2018-08-24` edge values:

```
df['vacation'] = 0
df.loc['2018-06-24':'2018-08-24'] = 1
print (df)
           a  vacation
2018-01-01  1         0
2018-01-02  1         0
2018-01-03  1         0
2018-01-04  1         0
2018-01-05  1         0
       ..       ...
2018-08-22  1         1
2018-08-23  1         1
2018-08-24  1         1
2018-08-25  1         0
2018-08-26  1         0

[238 rows x 2 columns]
```